# how to use grep to find exact number of characters?

Tags: unix, grep

let say if I want to grep any words that has 3 characters only in a dictionary. How do I use grep/egrep to achieve it?

I try egrep '.*+.*+.*+' but it includes everything...

Answer (score 1):

```
grep '^...$' mydict.txt
```

The ^ means it has to start at the beginning of the line, and the $ means it must end at the end.

Answer (score 1):

This should work:

```
grep -o '\b...\b' inputFile
```

**Note:** The output will be on a new line even though 3 character word is seen on same line. But for your usage on a dictionary where one word would appear on a line, this should work just fine.

```
$ cat f
balls bat cat mats rat
cri bee buffalo
cow mop boss

$ grep -o '\b...\b' f
bat
cat
rat
cri
bee
cow
mop
```

Comment: Might `.{3}` be "cleaner"?

Comment: @squiguy Absolutely. Since it was only 3 character words using `...` saved a character. :) But say for 10 character words `.{10}` is more appropriate.